# Artifactory Dependency Rewrite for NPM fails when used with npm-shrinkwrap

Tags: github, url-rewriting, npm, repository, artifactory

We are running Artifactory 4.7.7 rev 40199, with the aim of having all our NPM traffic for the project going through Artifactory. We are having issues with the combination of `npm-shrinkwrap` and External Dependency Rewrites for Github.

Our setup currently looks like this

- *npm-virtual* ( virtual repo that NPM is pointed at with the projects .npmrc file. Points at the below repositories in this order. Has External Dependency Rewrite set up for Github)

  - *npm-local* ( local repo for our own packages )
  - *registry-npmjs-org* ( remote repo for caching packages from the official NPM registry
  - *npm-github-rewrite* ( remote repo for caching rewritten Github repositories)

The issue we are seeing is replicatable by the following

- `npm install` a package with Github dependencies (`jsdoc@3.4.0`)
- Artifactory rewrites and caches the Github dependency (`taffydb` & `esprima`)
- `npm shrinkwrap` to lock down the versions
- Delete `node_modules`
- Run `npm install`

With Node setup to not use our proxy, the second `npm install` fails with the following message

```
npm ERR! fetch failed https://github.com/hegemonic/taffydb/tarball/7d100bcee0e997ee4977e273cdce60bd8933050e
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 192.30.253.112:443
npm ERR! fetch failed https://github.com/ariya/esprima/tarball/49a2eccb243f29bd653b11e9419241a9d726af7c
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 192.30.253.112:443
npm ERR! fetch failed https://github.com/ariya/esprima/tarball/49a2eccb243f29bd653b11e9419241a9d726af7c
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 192.30.253.113:443
npm ERR! fetch failed https://github.com/hegemonic/taffydb/tarball/7d100bcee0e997ee4977e273cdce60bd8933050e
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 192.30.253.113:443
npm ERR! fetch failed https://github.com/ariya/esprima/tarball/49a2eccb243f29bd653b11e9419241a9d726af7c
npm ERR! fetch failed https://github.com/hegemonic/taffydb/tarball/7d100bcee0e997ee4977e273cdce60bd8933050e
npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency /jsdoc/taffydb:
npm WARN Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 192.30.253.113:443
npm WARN     at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1012:11)
npm WARN     at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1035:20)
npm WARN     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1080:14)
npm WARN  { Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 192.30.253.113:443
npm WARN     at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1012:11)
npm WARN     at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1035:20)
npm WARN     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1080:14)
npm WARN   code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
npm WARN   errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
npm WARN   syscall: 'connect',
npm WARN   address: '192.30.253.113',
npm WARN   port: 443,
npm WARN   parent: 'jsdoc',
npm WARN   optional: '/jsdoc/taffydb' }
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10586
npm ERR! argv "D:\\Languages\\NodeJS\\node.exe" "D:\\Languages\\NodeJS\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! node v6.3.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.3
npm ERR! code ECONNREFUSED
npm ERR! errno ECONNREFUSED
npm ERR! syscall connect

npm ERR! Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 192.30.253.113:443
npm ERR!     at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1012:11)
npm ERR!     at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1035:20)
npm ERR!     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1080:14)
npm ERR!  { Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 192.30.253.113:443
npm ERR!     at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1012:11)
npm ERR!     at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1035:20)
npm ERR!     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1080:14)
npm ERR!   code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
npm ERR!   errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'connect',
npm ERR!   address: '192.30.253.113',
npm ERR!   port: 443,
npm ERR!   parent: 'jsdoc' }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
```

For some reason the presence of the shrinkwrap appears to completely ignore the dependency rewrite rules and just tries to go to Github anyway.

Are we missing something? Is there some setup step we are missing?

---

Additional details based on @uriah-l post

1. The `npm-shrinkwrap.json` contains only references to Artifactory URLs. There are no GitHub references in that file.
2. The local cached version of the package has it's `_resolved`, `_from` and `tarball` properties in it's `package.json` (stored next to the tgz) set to Artifactory urls/versions
3. The local cached version DOES have a reference to Github in it's `repository.url` property
4. The installed (`{INSTALL_DIR}/node_modules/taffydb/package.json`) version of the package has it's `_resolved`, `_from` and `tarball` properties in it's `package.json` set to Artifactory urls/versions`
5. The artifactory cached version of the original package (`jsdoc@3.4.0`) appears to have it's `package.json` in the tgz unchanged
6. The Artifactory Npm Info tab for the original package DOES have a GitHub URL rather than a version number for the other package (`taffydb`)
7. The versions of the pacakges that have been rewritten (`taffydb`) are appearing in the right repo (`npm-github-rewrite`), and their unpacked `package.json` appears to be unchanged

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the NPM client relies on the "_resolved" field that's inside the installed package's package.json file when it constructs the npm-shrinkwrap.json file (see [this client code](https://github.com/npm/npm/blob/master/lib/shrinkwrap.js#L111)), which I believe the NPM client itself adds to the package.json once it's installed. From that point the client simply follows whatever's inside this file on consequent install attempts, so if one of the dependency URLs points to something which isn't Artifactory, it will go there (also disregarding your ~/.npmrc registry URL, see [this discussion](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/6444))

While Artifactory re-writes the "tarball" field in the package.json, to date, even if it could deliberately alter the _resolved field somehow, it currently does not do so, assuming of course that there is fact a scenario in which you will actually get a package from Artifactory that has an extraneous "_resolved" field despite the fact that it was resolved from Artifactory - which I'm not at all sure is even possible (we do happen to have [a feature request](https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/RTFACT-12025) for that, although I can't say for sure whether or not it will be implemented).

**EDIT/Clarification** - I'm not sure whether the "_resolved" field is purely a client side field and can't exist on packages in the registry, in which case it sounds like something that could be outside the scopes of what Artifactory should handle.

That being said, when I ran your reproduction steps (resolving from Artifactory), the npm-shrinkwrap.json file only had my artifactory URL in it for all dependencies, which doesn't seem to be the case for you. I think this is most likely happening due to either one of the below reasons:

1.Your Artifactory cache contains an original (non-rewritten) copy of the 'taffydb' package - although I believe this is less likely, considering the fact that you are able to install it on the first attempt.
2.Or, your NPM cache (~/.npm/) or global node_modules dir contains an original copy of the 'taffydb' package.

All in all, you should be able to verify this by examining the {INSTALL_DIR}/node_modules/taffydb/package.json file, and check what's the value of the "_resolved" field. You can also try to modify it to be your Artifactory URL and see whether that fixes the npm-shrinkwrap.json file when it's regenerated.

HTH,

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. I have added some additional comments to the bottom of my original question.